# How does AJAX requests work exactly?

Tags: ajax, request

I had in mind to make a website that pulls data from steam statistics to show how many players are currently playing a specific game. Is this possible or does it have to be an actual api?

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning on this website only ever being a platform that displays the information you're pulling from the Steam API when users access your site, then no, you don't necessarily have to create a public-facing API.

However, if you're creating this application with the idea that *other* applications are going to programmatically retrieve the data you're displaying on the site, then yes, you should create an API that allows other applications to consume your data.

The best way to do the latter would be to create an independent service that consumes data from the Steam API and transforms it, then makes it available publicly (with authentication if deemed necessary). This API would then be consumed by a client that you create (your website that displays the data) as well as any other application that could make use of the data.